# Using Pipeline to Direct Files to Program that Opens Them

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, files, terminal

I have a `Music` folder, in which I have some music tracks, which aren't organized too well. Thus, if I want to find a particular track, I usually type: `ls Music | grep <keyword>`, where `<keyword>` is some keyword I expect the filename to have. Then my command line will return the name of the file for which I am looking, `<name>`, and then to open the music file, I will type `vlc <name> &`.

My question is whether it would be possible to streamline all of this into one operation? I tried using `ls Music | grep <keyword> | vlc`, but this was unsuccessful. How would I go about doing this?

(More generally, how would I use the pipeline for this sort of purpose?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `xargs` for this. It will take what is piped in on stdin and use it as arguments to a subcommand. So in your case it might look like this:

```
ls Music | grep <keyword> | xargs vlc &
```

Now, this command sequence will probably still have some issues, notably whitespace. By default, `xargs` will split its input on any whitepsace, so if you had a file named like `Artist Name - Track Name.mp3`, then `xargs` will send 5 separate arguments to `vlc`: `Artist`, `Name`, `-`, `Track`, `Name.mp3`. Luckily there's a way around this. If you use the `-0` option to `xargs`, it will use null `\0` to split its input into arguments to the sub command. And as it turns out the `find` command supports writing out file name matches with a null separator (and `find` is a better tool for finding files than `ls | grep` anyway).

So this may be a better pipeline:

```
find Music -iname '*<keyword>*' -print0 | xargs -0 vlc &
```

Answer (score 3):

While leaning how to use xargs is very useful, in this *particular* case it'd be better to just use a glob.

```
vlc Music/*keyword* &  ## will find all filenames containing the string 'keyword'
```

If you want recursiveness (that is: looking in subdirectories) then you could use the globstar shell option:

```
shopt -s globstar
vlc Music/**/*keyword* &
```

Comment: This is a better way of accomplishing this task. Thanks!